# How to make UITextView scroll up at specific row instead of the last row?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I'd like to make a `UITextView` looks like `UITextView` in Notes application but I don't know how to make it scroll up at specific row instead of the last row as default when press return. If not, a few rows at the bottom of `UITextView` will be overlapped by the virtual keypad.

Any idea, solution would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *contentOffset* property inherited from the UIScrollView, although you will need to calculate the row position yourself.